# Problems with AJAX control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ajax, updatepanel

I'm new to AJAX, and i've just received a project to improve full of this issue.
I've studied AJAX briefly, then i know all the consepts and some simple features. and i also know that while developins, it's extremely different from the deployed general look.
In the middle of one of the screens, there's this:
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/Exception.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/Exception.png)

I'm new to the project as well, so i've browsed through the solution and i've gone until where the control is located. It's composed of ASPX with VB.NET (but since i know C#, you could absolutely choose the language you're more comfortable with to answer)

asp code of the control:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TABsControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="Common_TABsControl" %>

<asp:Panel runat="server" BackImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Common/TABsBackground.png" >
   <asp:Repeater ID="TABsRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetTABs() %>' >
      <HeaderTemplate><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr></HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <td style="width:100px; max-width:100px; height:30px; max-height:30px; line-height:30px; vertical-align:30px; text-align:center;" >
         <asp:Panel runat="server" BackImageUrl='<%# eval("BackgroundImage") %>' >
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# eval("Text") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# eval("URL") %>' Enabled='<%# eval("Enabled") And My.User.IsAuthenticated %>' />
         </asp:Panel>
         </td>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate></tr></table></FooterTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code behind is composed of a Data Table, a function called "insert tabs" and "add row"

info:
[0](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)-I'll add any required information needed, i'm checking this question frequently
1-If needed, i'll post part of the VB code, but it uses components.
2-I am using VS 08
3-The project runs perfectly, with absolutely no flaws, but in the development part, it's even harder finding what to do when you have this in your screen
4-There's a constant BLOCK sign in the cursos whenever i roll the mouse over the control in the design tab as well as the area where it should be.

Comment: It worked! it just didn't refresh somehow. I wish i could mark both answers right, because both appeared in the same browser refresh and both are right, but i've chosen the one marked as first answer by timing. Thanks!

Comment: One last question, why did it work even though the id wasn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified ID for your `<asp:panel>` (?)

This should solve the issue

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Common/TABsBackground.png" >
```

Answer (score 1):

The very first line
 
is missing the id attribute. You can give any id for eg:= id="pnlRepeater"

All the Dotnet Server controls must have id="" & runat="server" attributes set.